# Magento global category filter

Tags: php, magento

We have a site with many categories and products. Now we want to add 3 global categories. One category for example could be "mobile telephones".

If the user clicks on this global filter, we want to remove all categories from the navigation and all products from all product lists which don't have the selected category. So after the click on the global category the site should only display products and categories which match to the selected global category.

Where do we have to apply the global filter?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/filter-product-collection-by-category

Comment: That's a normal collection filter. But I would like to know, how I can set a filter global for the whole website and where.